# Debezium MySQL Connector- com.mysql.cj.CharsetMapping.getStaticCollationNameForCollationIndex(Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/String

Tags: maven, quarkus, mysql-connector, debezium

Debezium mysql connector fail at final stage of snapshotting.
The project is on maven/quarkus , and I want to use debezium/infinispan for cache invalidation .

The Observer and configuration looks like this :

public void startEmbeddedEngine(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object init) throws IOException {
File dbHistoryTempFile = File.createTempFile("offsets", ".dat");
File offsetStorageTempFile = File.createTempFile("dbhistory", ".dat");

```
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("name", "cache-invalidation-engine");
    props.setProperty("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector");
    props.setProperty("offset.storage.file.filename", offsetStorageTempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    props.setProperty("offset.flush.interval.ms", "0");

    props.setProperty("database.hostname", "localhost");
    props.setProperty("database.port", "3306");
    props.setProperty("database.user", "root");
    props.setProperty("database.password", "password");
    props.setProperty("database.server.id", "1");
    props.setProperty("database.server.name", "new_feature");
    props.setProperty("database.history",
        "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory");
    props.setProperty("database.history.file.filename", dbHistoryTempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    props.setProperty("database.include.list", "database");


    // props.setProperty("database.history.file.filename","C:/Users/a.pogonet/AppData/Local/Temp/db.dat");
    props.setProperty("snapshot.mode", "never");
    // props.setProperty("include.unknown.datatypes", "true");
    // props.setProperty("include.schema.changes", "false");

    DebeziumEngine<ChangeEvent<String, String>> engine = DebeziumEngine.create(Json.class)
            .using(props)
            .notifying(record -> {
                System.out.println(record);
            }).build();

    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.execute(engine);
}
```

2021-12-09 14:18:34,137 INFO  [io.deb.con.mys.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource] (blc-localhost:3306) Stopped reading binlog after 0 events, no new offset was recorded
Exception in thread "blc-localhost:3306" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.cj.CharsetMapping.getStaticCollationNameForCollationIndex(Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/String;
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.antlr.MySqlAntlrDdlParser.extractCharset(MySqlAntlrDdlParser.java:404)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.antlr.listener.CreateAndAlterDatabaseParserListener.enterCreateDatabaseOption(CreateAndAlterDatabaseParserListener.java:49)
at io.debezium.ddl.parser.mysql.generated.MySqlParser$CreateDatabaseOptionContext.enterRule(MySqlParser.java:5912)
at io.debezium.antlr.ProxyParseTreeListenerUtil.delegateEnterRule(ProxyParseTreeListenerUtil.java:46)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.antlr.listener.MySqlAntlrDdlParserListener.enterEveryRule(MySqlAntlrDdlParserListener.java:89)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.enterRule(ParseTreeWalker.java:41)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:25)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker.walk(ParseTreeWalker.java:28)
at io.debezium.antlr.AntlrDdlParser.parse(AntlrDdlParser.java:87)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlDatabaseSchema.parseDdl(MySqlDatabaseSchema.java:216)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlDatabaseSchema.parseStreamingDdl(MySqlDatabaseSchema.java:202)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.handleQueryEvent(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:573)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$execute$14(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:827)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.handleEvent(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:349)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$execute$25(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:855)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:1125)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:973)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:599)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:857)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Answer (score 0):

The Quarkus BOM is enforcing a version of the MySQL driver and AFAICS Debezium is using methods that are not available anymore in this version of the driver.

What I recommend you is to use the version of the driver used by the Debezium connector by overriding the version manually in your project.

I can't tell you exactly which version to use given I have no idea which Debezium version you are using. But the version is there for Debezium 1.8: https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/1.8/pom.xml#L120 .

That being said, Quarkus 2.5.1.Final+ is also using MySQL Connector 8.0.27 so if you use these versions, I believe it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I also assumed that problem is in versions incompatibility. 
I use quarkus 1.10.5.Final and mysql 8.0.25. For debezium I took last stable version 1.7.1.Final . Could you provide please some upgrade/downgrade of versions to achive full compatibility ?

Comment: Done . I resolve the error by changing debezium version to 1.2.5 . Just don't know why 1.7.1 didn't work . Maybe you could explain  shortly!

Answer (score 0):

you need update mysql driver to 8.0.27

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```